# How to add admin-style inputs in a form (PDF)

Tags: python, forms, pdf

I want to create a form with fillable inputs with python in the following [image: format].

I tried several different pdf libraries but none of them were able to generate such inputs. I would like to know which library was used to produce these forms, and if I am able to do it with python.

I had a look at the blob library and also `aspose` library but it didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you want to create input fields that has different sections? Please provide some more details about the specific fields that you are not able to create using Aspose.PDF. It is also requested that you create a post in dedicated Aspose.PDF [support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) where you will be assisted accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of controlled field you are looking for is a "managed by script" field type called a `comb`. It is designed to be used in Adobe Acrobat compatible readers but should also function in any Acroform without scripting as in this case restricted by form management to 37 characters.

[image]

Thus you need to use any generator that includes the ability to produce comb fields. This is usually done by a sighted author in a GUI editor or graphics application (Often Adobe InDesign, as used above) since it needs visual placement and adjustments (over the graphics) and setting the programming controls.

In a simple graphics programming case like this, the "Designer" will usually be the "Programmer" too.

Apryse products may set it in code like this

```
field.SetFlag(Annot.Flag.e_comb, true);
field.GetSDFObj().PutNumber(“MaxLen”, 37);
```

a better description on use and limitations in Apryse iText was given in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57346920/10802527

Thus it is a regular feature in Java or C based PDF libs, but not usually found in Python PDF generators.

**However I note in PyPDF docs  under `class FfBits:`.

It has a "flag" entry for `Comb = 1 << 24  # Tx`**
https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pypdf/constants.html?highlight=comb%20#

**In PyMuPDF the widgets flag is naturally the same** but the syntax is

`PDF_TX_FIELD_IS_COMB  1 << 24`
https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vars.html#widget-flags-field-flags

Comment: Yeah I see, if you were given to do this in C, how would you do it ? I have limited knowledge in C/C# but if there are no alternatives, let's go for it !

Answer (score 0):

There are python libs that can do that, here's one I've used:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfform

def create_fillable_form():
    c = canvas.Canvas("fillable_form.pdf")
    form = c.acroForm

    # Create a text field
    c.drawString(100, 700, "Name:")
    form.textfield(name='name', tooltip='Enter your name', x=150, y=690, width=200)

    # Create a checkbox
    c.drawString(100, 650, "Agree to terms:")
    form.checkbox(name='agree', tooltip='Check to agree', x=180, y=640)

    c.save()

create_fillable_form()
```

[More documentation here](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf)

There are also ways to convert an HTML page to a PDF if that's easier

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I already did some forms that way but i really want to have each character separated (like the form above). When printed, it makes forms way more readable. I tried to look in the doc of reportlab but i don't see anything similar